# Can I use my sling while on the ceiling using Spider Climb?

Tags: spells, labyrinth-lord

Spider climb lets me climb walls and ceilings by making my hands and feet stick to surfaces.

The spell specifics from the *Labryinth Lord Advanced Edition Companion*

> The subject can climb and travel on vertical surfaces or even traverse ceilings as well as a spider does. The affected creature must have its hands and feet free and bare to climb in this manner. Any objects weighing fewer than 5 pounds cling to the spell recipient's hands. No spells may be cast when under the effect of this spell. This spell may be used on another being (touch required) with no saving throw.

Can I load and loose a sling bullet while clinging to the ceiling, without falling?

I *suspect* the GM might rule I'd fall, but I might suggest that if I loaded the sling first, climbed to the ceiling with loaded sling in mouth, then I only need to let go with one hand to use it, three points of bare contact on the surface would remain. If I fall, the cinematic play and possible surprise might be worth the attempt.

So does this work in Labyrinth Lord.

Comment: Any sensible DM will force this to play out like a Three Stooges episode.  You are upside-down, everything your hands touch tends to stick to you, and you're trying to use a weapon with multiple small parts.  Unless you've practiced this *a lot* there's no way that it ends well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The affected creature must have its hands and feet free and bare to climb in this manner.

Holding a sling doesn’t leave your hand free, thus you cannot climb in that manner, and barring any other way to stick to the wall or ceiling, it certainly seems to me that you would fall.

Answer (score 9):

Even assuming you don't fall, you need to release one end of a sling to release the bullet; this is not possible if items smaller than 5 pounds stick to your hands.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're assumed to walk on all fours, I suspect it's only logical that while you move, not all 4 of your limbs are always touching the surface. I would assume you could hang in place only using 3 limbs (probably only 2), but not able to move this way.

The other problem is the 5 pound objects rule. I would say that when you swing the sling, the momentum of the stone applies way more than 5 pounds on the string-loop that you're holding on so you could release it, though a stickler GM would apply a penalty on your attack anyway because of the sticky finger. You'd be better served by a crossbow, where you only touch the trigger and the bolt is held in place somewhat and will not fall while you climb (like the rock in the sling). You have to load the crossbow or sling before you cast the spell (or someone else loads them for you) though. A bow is probably right out since you're touching the arrow when you aim (or even heavier penalties).